# Redmine installation, can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, redmine

I'm trying to install redmine on a server with SQL Server Express 2008 R2, i've got ruby and rails installed but I've hit a standstill when trying to create the db structures, particularly in this step:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

rake aborted!
Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
```

Created db in SSMS with this command:

```
USE [master]
GO

-- Very basic DB creation
CREATE DATABASE [REDMINE]
GO

-- Creation of a login with SQL Server login/password authentication and no password expiration policy
CREATE LOGIN [REDMINE] WITH PASSWORD=N'redminepassword', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[REDMINE], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

-- User creation using previously created login authentication
USE [REDMINE]
GO
CREATE USER [REDMINE] FOR LOGIN [REDMINE]
GO
-- User permissions set via roles
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'REDMINE'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'REDMINE'
GO
```

My databse.yml file is the following:

```
production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: REDMINE
  host: localhost
  username: REDMINE
  password: redminepassword
```

I have a database with the corresponding name and login, any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: have installed necessary gem(s)? I [think](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/66084c8f9753a9b3646a754d933b98965d5b968b/Gemfile#L68-L70) you need `tiny_tds` and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`. What do you have if run `bundle show activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`?

Comment: I have `tiny_tds-0.5.1-x86-mingw32` and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12`

Comment: Maybe TCP/IP port is not Enabled - http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dbaces/2012/05/23/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-when-using-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Already did that as well. I'll update the question with the command I used to create the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decided to go with a [3rd party installation bundle](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Download#Third-party-Redmine-bundles) which uses a MySQL backend instead of SQL Server, worked like a charm. Moral of the story: SQL Server + Redmine + Windows Server = tears.

Answer (score 1):

This is my environment info:

```
bundle show activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.6

bundle show tiny_tds
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.2
```

Every time I do a minor change in config files, I run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle install --without development test --without development test
```

When I try to exec db:migrate, I get a tinyTDS error:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/htmlentities-4.3.1/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: duplicated key at line 466 ignored: "inodot"
rake aborted!
TinyTds::Error: Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
```

## Possible Issues

First thing about configuration, is that you have to point config/database.yml to the Listener IP, and no to the sql server databases.

```
production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: redmine
  host: listener.mysqlserver.myorg.com
  username: redmine
  password: mypass
```

Using TCPDump, you can also check that database answers to your redmine instance:

```
  tcpdump -i eth0 | grep listener.mysqlserver.myorg.com
```

There has to be traffic in both ways. Otherwise there is a timeout due to: database configuration, network routes, user, password....

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

1. Is TCP/IP connection enabled in **SQL Server Configuration Manager**?
2. Is **Server Authentication** set to **SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode**?
3. Can you connect to the server from SSMS or Visual Studio?
4. Though for Express Edition, TinyTDS documents say it can connect through SQL Browser, but in my experince it CAN NOT! So, find the port SQL is listenning and set it in the configuratin file.There is also no need to mention the named instance in the configuration file.
5. Is Firewall ON or OFF? If ON, is SQL port open or not?

And finally here is the configuration file that works fine for me:

```
production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: 'WIN10'
  #instance: SSE2K14
  port: 53540
  database: redmine
  username: REDMINE1 # should match the database user name
  password: "redminepassword" # should match the login password
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Express, I had to use the IP address for `host` and change the `port`.

Something like this in database.yaml:

`production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: REDMINE
  host: 192.168.0.20
  username: REDMINE
  password: hot-dang-47-balls!
  port: 63151`

Your IP address and port might be different.  Check here: SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS > TCPIP (Properties).